# truffle unbox react, unhandled rejection

Tags: reactjs, truffle

I keep getting this error

"Unhandled Rejection (Error): This contract object doesn't have address set yet, please set an address first.
"
when launching truffle unbox react, and also I don't have truffle.js, only have truffle-config.js

Comment: when I install truffle unbox react, I always get this error....

Answer (score 4):

Late but hopefully this will answer the question as I have ran into the same issue.

Assuming your metamask extension is enabled, make sure to switch your network to the localhost that is running either ganache-cli or truffle.