# After running truffle unbox react getting error

Tags: reactjs, solidity, truffle, ganache

After first initialization of running truffle compile then truffle unbox react getting error Unhandled Rejection (Error): This contract object doesn't have address set yet, please set an address first.
I am trying to install a react dapp so i can learn how to create dapps so i am a beginner but i dont understand why i woulg get an error after first initialization. Also when i ran truffle unbox react it didnt complete it stopped at downloading and didnt do anything after that so it did not set up the box. then i tried [truffle unbox react, unhandled rejection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56980736/truffle-unbox-react-unhandled-rejection) and that didnt work so i tried https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X3vdaNY9KYQ and that didnt work either. To explain I went to ganache and settings and changed the port number to 8545 and then connected to local host 8545 in metamask then i changed my hostname to the numbers in node for on your network because the localhost did not work either. The farthest to a difference i got was connecting to my network and now the page is stuck at loading web3,accounts, and contract and a dialog box popped up and gave me this error.

Failed to load web3, accounts, or contract. Check console for details